# How to debug javascript code inside ant build file with eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, debugging, ant

I have a big ant build file that contains inline javascript code and also references to sepparate javascript files for some of the more complex build tasks.

I would like to know if it is possible to debug the javascript code with eclipse.

Following are examples from the ant build file that use javascript. Note that a sepparate .js file is also used. I really need to debug the contents on that file:

```
<target name="validateProject" >

    <!-- Execute the project analysis -->
    <script language="javascript" src="${basedir}/Validate.js" />

    <!-- Check if the build must fail or not -->
    <fail if="javascript.fail.message" message="${javascript.fail.message}" />

</target>


<!-- Launch the Js unit tests via local web server -->
<target name="runJsTestsLocalServer">

    <!-- Append all the Js code to the index.js file -->
    <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[

            if(project.getProperty("Release.generate") == "true"){

                self.project.executeTarget("runJsTestsAuxConcatFromRelease");

            }else{

                self.project.executeTarget("runJsTestsAuxConcatFromBuild");
            }

        ]]>
    </script>

</target>
```